Using vite / rollup with npm workspaces, issue with react on production build
I am trying to create a local shared folder / workspace / package to share code between projects in a monorepo using npm workspaces, and it works in vite dev mode, but not when I build and preview using vite / rollup.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at react_production_min.useState (index.js:85289:286)
    at useDebounceValue (index.js:86924:53)
    at AppContainer (index.js:86942:36)

This is my folder structure:
my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ packages/
│  ├─ shared/
│  ├─ app/
├─ package.json


This is my root package.json:
{
  "name": "frontends",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Our frontends",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.17",
    "postcss": "8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.1"
  }
}

This my shared package.json
{
  "name": "@myscope/shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shared components, libraries and utils for frontend projects",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "i18next": "23.11.3",
    "oidc-client-ts": "2.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.2.1",
    "i18next": "23.11.3",
    "oidc-client-ts": "2.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}

And I have a single React hook in shared:
import React from "react";

/**
 * Debounced value update, e.g. to trigger search after a user stops typing
 * @param value
 * @param delay
 */
export default function useDebounceValue(value: string, delay: number) {
  // State and setters for debounced value
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = React.useState(value);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [value]);

  return debouncedValue;
}


This is the app vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import { htmlInjectionPlugin } from "vite-plugin-html-injection";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  preview: {
    port: 5174,
  },
  server: {
    port: 5174,
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    htmlInjectionPlugin({
      injections: [
        {
          name: "Global Config",
          path: "./public/config.js",
          type: "js",
          injectTo: "head",
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    assetsDir: "public/assets",
    outDir: "./build",
    minify: false,
    target: "esnext",
    assetsInlineLimit: 8192,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`,
      },
    },
  },
  base: "./",
});


And inside app I have an appContainer.tsx where I try to use useDebounceValue (as a test only)
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useDebounceValue } from "@myscope/shared/react/hooks";

import { MenuItem } from "../core/models/menu";
import { RootState } from "../core/state/dependencies";


export const AppContainer = () => {
  const activeMenu: MenuItem | null | undefined = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.menu.activeMenu,
  );

  const debouncedTest = useDebounceValue(activeMenu?.title, 500);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.info(debouncedTest);
  }, [debouncedTest]);

  return (
    <div>Test</div>
  );
};


In vite dev this runs fine, but if I do vite build && vite preview, it fails with the null error from the top.
If I inspect the index.js that rollup builds, I see that all usage of react from the "app" uses the following react ref:
var reactExports$1 = react$1.exports;
const React$1 = /*@__PURE__*/getDefaultExportFromCjs(reactExports$1);

But the one from useDebounceValue seem to have it's own react reference which ends up being null.
var reactExports = react.exports;
const React = /*@__PURE__*/getDefaultExportFromCjs(reactExports);

/**
 * @license React
...

function useDebounceValue(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = React.useState(value);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handler = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handler);
    };
  }, [value]);
  return debouncedValue;
}


What am I doing wrong here?

The issue was that I had an old package-lock.json in one of the packages with react deps that I didn't think of. Deleting it, and making sure none of the packages had react as a dependency (I only have it in the root package.json) made it work.
